# Hide and unhide series in a chart based on their name and i have error 1104

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide and unhide series in a chart based on their name using excel vba and I have a error 1004 invalid parameter after the first run of the for cycle.

```
Sub macroChart3()
'
' macroChart3 Macro test 
'
Dim i, n As Integer

For i = 1 To 96 Step 1
    If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = "*contracted*" Then
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = False
    Else
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = True
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SeriesCollection.IsFiltered method seemed to toggle this check box:
[image: Excel series visible check box]

I couldn't use that. I wanted to record macro and see if any other method is used but the checkbox is gone in 2010:
[image: No check box in 2010]

So it might be not possible to use that anymore. If you are using a different version where this method exists you might have a problem that the series is not listed in in seriesCollection anymore:

---

[Remarks from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj230730.aspx)

*When a user filters out a series, the series IsFiltered property switches to True, and the series is transferred out of its parent SeriesCollection.*

See if you can use FullSeriesCollection instead when you change the visibility of series:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = True
```

If that doesn't work you might add and remove ranges instead of hiding them.

### **UPDATE:**

Run your macro in step mode (F8) so you have full visibility of the execution steps. Add your evaluated expressions (ones that are used within IFs) to see their result and you will find out if they are incorrect or are evaluated as FALSE and try to figure out why.
[image: Step mode with watch list]
And don't forget to up vote the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I figured it out, I had a problem in the if statements. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, just out of curiosity, what was the problem?

Comment: I used this syntax for the main if clause: If (InStr(1, ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name, "high", vbBinaryCompare) > 0) Then

Comment: What if people are using excel 2010? There is no FullSeriesCollection in the excel object model

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the quick reply, the error is fixed, but still not all the series are processed by the if clauses in the for cycle, for example this statement:

```
Else
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = True
    End If
```

Isn't executed and I don't understand why.